# Using the standard basis of $\mathbb R^2$, determine the matrix of a reflection in a line forming an angle $\frac{\theta}{2}$ with the $x$-axis.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Using the standard basis of $\mathbb R^2$, determine the matrix of a reflection in a line forming an angle $\frac{\theta}{2}$ with the $x$-axis.

I am trying to draw and conceptualise a reflection in a line forming an angle $\frac{\theta}{2}$ with the $x$-axis. The following diagram is basically how I am conceptualising it at the moment. [image]

My difficulty lies in envisioning what it means to have $e_2$ reflected across such a line. My initial thoughts are that it would be reflected directly downwards, to $(0,-1)$. However, I am told that this is incorrect. My question is, how would we reason about the reflection of $e_2$ across the line?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can decompose any vector $v$ into a component parallel to a vector $u$ and orthogonal to it:

$$v = v_\| + v_\bot$$

Hint 2: The matrix to project a vector onto a unit vector $a$ is $$\pmatrix{a_1 \\ a_2}\pmatrix{a_1 & a_2} = \pmatrix{{a_1}^2 & a_1a_2 \\ a_2a_1 & {a_2}^2}$$

General idea (in question form): can you express the reflection of a vector $v$ through the line $\operatorname{span}(u)$ in terms of $v_\|$ and $v_\bot$?

---

Edit: Here's the full answer.

From amd's picture, you can see that $Rv = v_\| - v_\bot$ for any vector $v$.  Using this and what we have above we get:

$$\begin{align}Rv &= v_\| - v_\bot \\ &= v_\| - (v-v_\|) \\ &= 2v_\| -v \\ &= 2Av-Iv \\ &= 2\pmatrix{{a_1}^2 & a_1a_2 \\ a_2a_1 & {a_2}^2}v-\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}v \\ &= \pmatrix{2{a_1}^2 - 1 & 2a_1a_2 \\ 2a_2a_1 & 2{a_2}^2-1}v\end{align}$$ $$\implies \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{R = \pmatrix{2{a_1}^2 - 1 & 2a_1a_2 \\ 2a_2a_1 & 2{a_2}^2-1}}$$

where $(a_1, a_2)$ is a unit vector parallel to your line.  In this case, that's clearly $\big(\cos(\theta/2),\sin(\theta/2)\big)$.

Note that while you could have done this been reflecting $e_1$ and $e_2$ and constructing the matrix from their images, this more abstract method is easier and I think more instructive.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand how to represent such a thing. I saw $v_‖$ and v$_\bot$ and starting playing around with the dot product definition, but I'm getting no where.

Comment: The [reflected vector](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~msapir/msapir/Images/reflection.gif) would just be $$Rv = v_\|-v_\bot$$

Comment: But I don't understand how one would find this. What is the vector $\mathbf v$ referring to?

Comment: An arbitrary vector.

Comment: But I don't understand what relation this vector has to the question. We've got $e_1$, $e_2$, and the line.

Comment: Let $R$ be your reflection matrix and $v$ an arbitrary vector to be reflected.  We know three things: (1) $v= v_\| + v_\bot$, (2) $v_\| = Av = \pmatrix{{a_1}^2 & a_1a_2 \\ a_2a_1 & {a_2}^2}v$ where $(a_1, a_2)$ is a unit vector parallel to the line being reflected over, and (3) the reflected vector will have the form $Rv = v_\| - v_\bot$ (convince yourself of this with a picture -- I can't find a good one online).  Then $$Rv = v_\| - v_\bot = Av - (v-v_\|) = 2Av-Iv = (2A-I)v$$  Therefore $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{R = 2A-I}$$

Comment: I'm afraid you're building off of something that I don't understand. What I've got right now is $e_1$, $e_2$, and the line, as shown in the image. I'm not sure which one of these you're abstracting as the vector $\mathbf v$, and I'm not sure how parallel or perpendicular vectors help me answer this question. If you could explain this to start off, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I assume you care about $e_1$ and $e_2$ because you know that a linear transformation is determined by its action on a basis?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: OK.  That's not the only way to figure out the matrix representing a transformation.  In my answer, I represent the transformation (/matrix) in terms of other transformations (/matrices).  Do we agree that it's possible in principle to do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46053/discussion-between-bye-world-and-the-pointer).

Answer (score 1):

This might be a case for which a picture is worth a thousand words.

[image]

Imagine a flat mirror along the line of reflection. Where does an object’s image appear to be? Directly opposite the object. To put this in mathematical terms, the line joining a point to its image is perpendicular to the line of reflection.

As Bye_World hints in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1945783/265466), this means that you can find the image of a vector $\mathbf v$ by decomposing it into a vector $\mathbf v_\perp$ that’s perpendicular to the line and a vector $\mathbf v_\parallel$ parallel to it. From the illustration, it should be clear that the image of $\mathbf v=\mathbf v_\parallel+\mathbf v_\perp$ is obtained by reversing the perpendicular component, i.e., $\mathbf v'=\mathbf v_\parallel-\mathbf v_\perp$. The basis vectors are no different: to find their images, you need to project them orthogonally onto the line to get the parallel component, from which you can find the perpendicular component and thus the reflected image.

With this information in hand, can you construct the reflection matrix?

Comment: Hi amd. I actually made significant progress and have created a new question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946116/using-the-standard-basis-of-mathbb-r2-determine-the-matrix-of-a-reflection I've encountered a new problem and would appreciate it if you could chime in. Thanks!